# Телебот, пайтон

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

[image: Хочу сделать что бы при добавлении бота в группу появились его команды, как на картинке]

Если что, то когда нажимаешь на "/", то должен появиться список команд:
/start
/new

Comment: @BotFather используй команду /setcommands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще, лучше через официальный бот @BotFather, как вам уже подсказал Андрей. Но если вы хотите вручную то так.

```
from telebot import TeleBot
from telebot.types import BotCommand

bot = TeleBot('123...')
commands = [BotCommand('start', 'Start bot'), BotCommand('new', 'New ...')]

bot.set_my_commands(commands)
```